# Reporting Service run too long then Error

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, dynamics-crm

I use VS2010 to make My report (MSCRM).
my report get 1 parameter(@project) as list of text 
I choose select all parameter value (around 100 value) and click "View Report" to generate my report I wait around 5 minutes then I got an Error

My test Query result only 599 Rows spend 2-13 sec in SQL server But Report Viewer in MSCRM spend around 5 minute Then error

So What happen in my report  and how to fix it.
I use Tablix to display result in report

Thank you.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I get this Error

Error
An Error has occurred.
Try this action again. If the problem continues,check the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Community for solutions or contect your organization's Microsoft Dynamics CRM Administrator. Finally , you can contact Microsoft Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found solution for my problem I think my problem about passing Multiple value parameter to Query. So I don't pass it to Query but I retrieve all Rows then Use Tablix Filters for filter rows

I follow this Article [SQL Server Reporting Service using Multi-value Parameters](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2866/sql-server-reporting-services-using-multivalue-parameters/)

and this suggestion by Rockit [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1b64454c-96ee-4d3a-95ca-6ef3bd41008e/ssrs-report-running-very-slow-but-query-is-very-fast-in-ssms)